# Patching Module in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, monkeypatching

I'm trying to add the following code that I found online as a workaround for a problem with combining MongoDB and Backbone.js in Rails, but I actually don't know Ruby/Rails that well because I'm learning all three at once.

Currently, I've just created a file in `lib/` called mongoid.rb with the following content:

```
module Mongoid
  module BackboneSerialization
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    module InstanceMethods
      def serializable_hash(options = nil)
        persisted? ? super.merge('id' => _id) : super
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Assuming that this code is correct, is there anything else I have to be aware of to make this work. All I'm doing now is adding this code and then starting my server but that doesn't seem to solve the problem. Is there a specific place I need to store it- like `lib/mongoid/backbone_serialization/instance_methods`? Or do I need to include this in certain files? If so, do I include just Mongoid or submodules?

Comment: Try putting the file in config/initializers and then restart rails

Answer (score 0):

#### config/environment.rb,

after `require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)`

and before `APPNAME::Application.initialize!`

add `require "mongoid"`